# Compile error when building doom_py on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python-2.7, cmake, pytorch, openai-gym, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to build doom_py on Ubuntu to no avail
Whenever I run **python setup.py build** command inside **doom_py** directory, and get the following errors.

**Setup**
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Python 2.7.14 (Anaconda 2)
- OpenAI Gym 0.9.5
- Vizdoom 1.1.4
- doom-py 0.0.14
- ppaquette/gym-doom

**Errors**

```
Scanning dependencies of target libvizdoom_static
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/src/lib/ViZDoomController.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/src/lib/ViZDoomExceptions.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp.o
/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/doom_py/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp: In member function ‘bool vizdoom::DoomGame::loadConfig(std::__cxx11::string)’:
/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/doom_py/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp:743:22: error: ‘cerr’ is not a member of ‘std’
                  std::cerr<<"WARNING! Loading config from: \""<<filename<<"\". Syntax erorr in line #"<<line_number<<". Line ignored.\n";
                      ^~~~
/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/doom_py/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp:743:22: note: suggested alternative: ‘erf’
                  std::cerr<<"WARNING! Loading config from: \""<<filename<<"\". Syntax erorr in line #"<<line_number<<". Line ignored.\n";
                      ^~~~
                      erf
/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/doom_py/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp:757:22: error: ‘cerr’ is not a member of ‘std’
                  std::cerr<<"WARNING! Loading config from: \""<<filename<<"\". Empty key in line #"<<line_number<<". Line ignored.\n";
                      ^~~~
/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/doom_py/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp:757:22: note: suggested alternative: ‘erf’
                  std::cerr<<"WARNING! Loading config from: \""<<filename<<"\". Empty key in line #"<<line_number<<". Line ignored.\n";
                      ^~~~
                      erf



                  erf
CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/src/lib/ViZDoomGame.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libvizdoom_static.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[1m
Could not build doom-py: Command '['make', '-j', '1']' returned non-zero exit status 2. (HINT: are you sure cmake is installed? You might also be missing a library. Try running 'apt-get install -y python-numpy cmake zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libboost-all-dev gcc libsdl2-dev wget unzip'

[0mTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/setup.py", line 88, in <module>
    include_package_data=True,
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/setup.py", line 63, in run
    build_func()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/setup.py", line 41, in build_linux
    build_common('so')
  File "/tmp/pip-build-fqKs1A/doom-py/setup.py", line 29, in build_common
    subprocess.check_call(['make', '-j', str(cores_to_use)], cwd='doom_py')
  File "/home/hybridsyntax/anaconda2/envs/doomenv/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-j', '1']' returned non-zero exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: pass VERBOSE=1 to make to see the actual compiler invocations. Does the source #include <iostream>

Comment: I gave up on solving this, as I could solve [my other problem on WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541672/getting-multiprocessing-lock-error-when-running-vizdoom-and-pytorch-program-on-w) and get it to work. I think creating a new environment and paying attention to the order and versions could be helpful.